# Is SharePoint 2013 Page History navigation panel in wikies editable?

Tags: wiki, version-history

Question says it all. If I go to Wiki page -> Page -> Page History a extra navigation panel called "Versions" appears which shows major, minor versions, date and time, also lets you to compare. If we would go deeper, f.e. Page -> Page History -> Version History we can see Comments which were added using Check In function. My question: Is that navigation panel "Versions" editable? For example, can I remove date and time? Can I add those comments here from Version History?